# Limit of a Bessel function is a Gaussian

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

Let $x$ and $\nu$ be real. Is the following true?

$$
e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}=\lim_{\nu\rightarrow\infty}\Gamma(\nu+1)\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt\nu x}\right)^\nu J_\nu\left(\sqrt{\nu} x\right),
$$

It appears to be true numerically, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Try to rewrite the differential equation with the change of variable $z:=\sqrt\nu x$ and the change of function $K_\nu(z):=t^{-\nu}J_\nu(z)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the first term of Gradshteyn & Rhyzhik 8.452 'approximation by tangents:'
$$ J_v\Big(\frac{v}{\cosh(a)}\Big) \sim \frac{\exp{(v \tanh(a) - v\,a)}}
{\sqrt{2\, v\,\pi \tanh(a) }} $$
Set $\cosh(a) = \sqrt{v}/x $ for fixed $x,$ so that this parameter is increasing, a necessity to use the formula.
Then $\tanh{a} = \sqrt{1-\text{sech }^2{ a}} = \sqrt{1-x^2/v} \to 1.$
Use $a=\text{arccosh(}\cosh(a)) \sim \log{\big(2\sqrt{v}/x \big)}-x^2/v.$  Use $\Gamma(v+1) \sim v^{v}\sqrt{2\pi\,v} \, e^{-v} .$  Substitute this into the right hand side of the equation, and algebra completes the proof.

Comment: Do you know any source with the derivation of the "tangent" approximation?

Comment: G&R has the source 'WA 269(3)' which apparently means 'Treatise of the Theory of Bessel Functions,' by G.N. Watson.

Comment: skbmoore, thank you